# Has any of the presidential candidates ever mentioned fixing our aging infrastructure?

Tags: united-states, parties, political-system, infrastructure

There's no denying, these recent historic floods we've been having in the past couple of years have only shown how our aging infrastructure needs to be fixed. No proper drainage systems, our roads are crumbling and falling apart, our bridges are 50+ years old making them dangerous etc...  Have either of the two candidates mentioned fixing our infrastructure and if not, WHY?

Answer (score 5):

Both Donald Trump and [Hillary Clinton](https://www.hillaryclinton.com/issues/fixing-americas-infrastructure/) have infrastructure plans.  Trump wants to spend twice as much as Clinton and may be a bit more construction focused.  Clinton's plan includes a banking component and energy spending.  Trump talks about bridges, roads, and airports.

Example source:  http://thehill.com/blogs/congress-blog/economy-budget/272108-infrastructure-in-a-trump-or-clinton-administration

Comment: Isn't most of the infrastructure mentioned in the question the responsibility of the states anyway?

Comment: @Philipp  It depends on whether the roads and bridges are local or interstate roads.  Note that drainage issues related to rivers are almost exclusively the province of the federal government.  And regardless of whether the states *should* handle them, many want the federal government to do so.  Clinton promotes her infrastructure plan as a jobs program like the [WPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Works_Progress_Administration).

Comment: @Philipp Even though infrastructure is mostly a state responsibility, they  generally depend heavily on federal subsidies.